# Import OpenLDAP directory into OSX Open Directory

Tags: linux, macos, ldap, openldap

We run a bunch of Macbook Pros and Airs at work, as well as a few Windows 7 boxes and some Ubuntu workstations. We use OpenLDAP for the Linux and Windows boxes, but all the Apple users have local accounts on their individual machines.

I've been mucking about with Open Directory on the OSX Server we use for Net Installs, and I've got a test user set up and I've been able to login over the network from another Mac.

I was wondering if it is possible to be able to sync Open Directory with the OpenLDAP server, which runs on Debian I think, so when a new user is added, it will add them as a user on the Open Directory as well, hence all users can log on to all machines and it's a massive win.

I'm not really that familiar with how LDAP works, so I'm totally winging it.

Any pointers would be great

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to use the OpenDirectory for the windows boxes but thats not the question.

You can use OpenLDAP as backend for your Macs. But the OpenLDAP has to implement the schema of the OpenDirectory (which in itself uses OpenLDAP as backend). Those schema-files are lokated in different places depending on the MacOSVersion you are using.

you have to place those files inside the OpenLDAPs schema folder and restart the ldap. After that you can extend the users to make use of that Information. But you will have to adapt the mapping of Information on the Mac-clients so that all relevant information from the LDAP ends up in the right places. Not an easy task. I'd think twice wheter it makes sense for a handfull or two of macBoxes. We've implemented for 150 Macs and it was a pain to get everything right.

And AFAIK there is no easy way of bringing an OpenLDAP and an OpenDirectoy in synch eith one another due to the schema extension apple used.

Depending on the frontend you use you might be able to implement a mechanism that adds a user to two LDAPs when the are created but what about changing passwords? Or changing a users name? you will have to do a lot of manual adaptions to make that possible.

So In my opinion not an easy task especially when you have to catch up on some LDAP stuff and the LDAP documentation of Apple is rather sparse...

Comment: Thanks. That's really useful advice.
We could probably script adding a new user to both LDAPS, but as you say, password changes will be a royal pain the arse.
It's quite frustrating as we really need to bring the Macs in line with everything else. It's a bit Wild West at the moment.
Thats food for thought though.
Thanks :)

Comment: Feel free to get in touch. As already said, we've been through the process ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your question title says "Import OpenLDAP directory into OSX Open Directory".

Which you certainly can. LDAP is a wire protocol.

Check out [PORTABLE HOME DIRECTORIES WITH OPENLDAP](http://cs.roosevelt.edu/eric/Portable_Home_Directories_w_OpenLDAP.html)

You then ask "is it possible to be able to sync Open Directory with the OpenLDAP server".
Yes, there are many IDM products out there that will allow sync two LDAP directories. NetIQ IDM, http://forgerock.com/, and many others. But, probably more than you want to deal with. (I think they are best for 1000+ Users)

Answer (score 0):

## Use below listed function and export that schema to LDIF  format.

> ldapmodify
>
> ## If possible then use ldap admin tool
>
> phpldapadmin,ldap admin etc
>   Export whole shema or branch in ldif and .xml(dsml) type.
>   Then Inport it to desired directory server by using admin tool else commandline  function 
>   ldapadd